# Compare string array with a single string entered by user , it also tell that it is found 2times &at that position

Tags: c++, string, compare

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{
    clrscr();

    char str[3][10], search[10];
    int i, t = 0, k;

    cout << "Enter 3 Names Of Fruit" << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        cin >> str[i];

    cout << "Enter Fruit Name To Search" << endl;
    cin >> search;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (search == str[i])   // if statement is not giving true
        {
            t++;
            k = i;
        }
    }

    cout << "The " << search << " is found " << t <<
        " times and is at position " << k << endl;

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using `std::string` ? The given program will work if you have `std::string str[3], search;` declaration instead. And you need to include `<string>` header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [std::strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) from cstring:

Full code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using std::strcmp;

int main() {

    char str[3][10], search[10];
    int i, t = 0, k;

    cout<<"Enter 3 Names Of Fruit"<<endl;

    for( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) 
        cin>>str[i];

    cout<<"Enter Fruit Name To Search"<<endl;
    cin>>search;

    for( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        if( strcmp(search, str[i]) == 0)
        { 
            t++;
            k=i;
        }
    }

    cout << "The " << search << " is found " << t
        << " times and is at position " << k + 1 << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
Enter 3 Names Of Fruit
banana mango orange
Enter Fruit Name To Search
mango
The mango is found 1 times and is at position 2
```

Comment: One more question please, how can we capitalize 1st letter of string entered by user such as "i am programmer" as "I Am Programmer"

Comment: From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/62826/#msg340148) This one changes just the first letter of the word to uppercase. To change first character of all words in a sentence, [use this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/62826/#msg341356)